# SAS informat for £ values using 9.1.3

Tags: sas

Is there a SAS informat which can be used in version 9.1.3 (similar to NLMNLGBP in 9.2) for reading in £ values?

eg below..

```
data;
x='£69';
y=input(x,NLMNLGBP3.);/* need 9.1.3 equivalent */
put y=;
run;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you set your locale to 'English_UnitedKingdom', you can use the `NLMNYw.d` informat.

example below:

```
options locale=English_UnitedKingdom;
data _null_;
  format x y best12.;
  x=input('(£69)',nlmny32.2); /* parenthesis represents negative */
  y=input('£69',nlmny32.2);
  put x= y=;
run;
```

/* On log */

```
x=-69 y=69
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this informat was available in 9.1.3 (according to google)

You could try this:

```
data _null_;
 x='£69';
 _x=input(compress(x,'£'),8.);
 y=put(_x,NLMNLGBP.);
 put y=;
run;
```